# Memcahced on multiple servers in PHP

Tags: php, memcached, load-balancing

I have the following question regarding the memcached module in PHP:

**Intro:**

We're using the module to prevent the same queries from being sent to the Database server, on a site with 500+ users in every moment.

Sometimes (very rarely) the memcahed process defuncts and all active users start generating queries to the database, so everything stops working.

**Question:**

I know, that memcached supports multiple servers, but I want to know what happens when one of them dies? Is there some sort of balancer background or something, that can tell `Ow! server 1 is dead. I'll send everything to server 2 until the server 1 goes back online.` or the load is being sent equally to each one?

**Possible sollutions:**

I need to know this, because if it's not supported our sysadmin can set the current memcached server to be a load ballancer and to balance the load between several other servers.

Should I ask him to create the load-balancing manualy or is this feature supported by default and what are the risks for both methods?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be supported by the client. Memcached servers don't know anything about themselves, they are just dummy K-V storages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add multiple servers in your PHP script, not in Memcache's configuration.

When you use `Memcached::addServers()`, you can specify a weight for every server. In your case, you might set one Memcache server to be higher than the other and only have the second act as a failover.

Using `Memcached::setOption()`, you can set how often a connection should be retried and set the timeout. If you know your Memcache servers die a lot, it might be worth it to set this lower than the defaults, but it shouldn't be necessary.